# Angular 9 route navigation waits until animations complete

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, angular-animations

For some reason when triggering a route navigation using the Router and a standard routing module, my route in the url changes to the new one immediately, however I get a lag on the screen as it reloads the current page I was on and waits until the animations complete before finally loading up the screen correctly.

I have just moved from Angular 8 to 9, and never had that problem before when working with 7 or 8. I work with other Angular 9 projects and never saw this issue before, and I was wondering if anyone else has had that issue ever?

Routing module:

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'fantasy', loadChildren: () => import('./sections/fantasy/fantasy.module').then(m => m.FantasyModule) },
  { path: 'club', loadChildren: () => import('./sections/club/club.module').then(m => m.ClubModule) },
  { path: 'profile', loadChildren: () => import('./sections/profile/profile.module').then(m => m.ProfileModule) },
  { path: 'stats', loadChildren: () => import('./sections/statistics/statistics.module').then(m => m.StatisticsModule) },
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Dependencies:

```js
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^9.0.0",
    "angularx-social-login": "^3.1.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "firebase": "^7.15.0",
    "jimp": "^0.9.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.900.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.803.15",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.0.0",
    "@babel/compat-data": "^7.8.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.59",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^8.2.0",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^5.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-jest": "^24.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tsickle": "^0.37.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "3.6.4"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.5.5"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "typescript": "3.6.4",
    "tslib": "1.10.0"
  }
```